# Elementor to custom wordpress page

Tags: php

I have a custom page that loads wordpress header and footer via `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions, but elementor is not loaded here.

How do I load elementor css/js to custom page?

Comment: In which file you can enque css/js files ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Page Template to either Elementor Full Width or Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `the_content()` to your code. Then, when you edit the page, elementor elements will be replaced with the_content(). So, the page template would be something similar to:

```
<?php
get_header();

if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
else: ?>
<p>Sorry, nothing found here.</p>
<?php
endif;

get_footer();

?>
```